# Terminal redirection command

Tags: terminal, cmd, alias

I have been working on a couple of projects now. Always as I am firing up my terminal, in mac, I start at the root folder, which is fine for most of the times. But I was wondering if there is a possibility to make a file which redirects you instantly to a map. Say for instance I have to type:

cd Desktop/justamap/justanothermap/andamap/etc.

Would it be possible to create a command file in the rootfolder, containing the full adress of the designated map, which would take me to the selected map just by for instance running it?

This could save me a lot of time when working on projects with time between them.

I am truly sorry if I am reposting a question but I just couldnt find something with my keywords.

Thx in advance, your help is appreciated!

Greetings,

Kipt Scriddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

it will open in vim u can use mate or anyhing else

```
 alias project='cd Desktop/justamap/justanothermap/andamap/etc.'
```

close your terminal and restart it. Bingo should work for you.

Working Great for me :)

Comment: Hmmmm think I am doing something wrong.. Opened the bash_profile and entered just a simple location like:
alias project = 'cd Desktop'
but as soon as a fire up my terminal it says: -bash: alias: project: not found. Any idea/suggestion?

Comment: EDIT: fixed it, had a space on both sides of the "=" sign :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple **sh file** (for instance ./anything_here) and run it:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd Desktop/justamap/justanothermap/andamap/etc

$ chmod +x ./anything_here
$ ./anything_here
```

You can also create a **symlink** to the folder, and then *cd* into the symlink (this will act like the folder is, in fact, *./anything_here*):

```
$ ln -s ./anything_here Desktop/justamap/justanothermap/andamap/etc
$ cd ./anything_here
```

Or you can create an **alias**, and write it on the console, putting this on your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile file:

```
alias anything_here="cd Desktop/justamap/justanothermap/andamap/etc"

$ anything_here
```